# How to tell Clementine the truth about Lee's past?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

In episode 2, my Lee and Carley talk about who knows about Lee's criminal past. I told her that Larry knows. My Lee then said something along the lines that Clementine might know, though he lied.

I was confused since I thought I told Clementine the truth. I suspect it was the conversation with Clementine after Carley confronted Lee about his past back in episode 1 that controls this outcome.

What do I have to say to Clementine in episode 1 for Lee to say in episode 2 that he did not lie?

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually hide this from her, since Carley will still be there. Instead, confront Clementine earlier and persuade her that your actions were justified.

Answer (score 1):

Same way you tell everybody else. After you're done with Carley, simply walk down to Clementine and pick "I need to tell you something..." then pick the "I've killed"/"I'm a murderer"/etc. option.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to say to Clementine in episode 1 for Lee to say in
>   episode 2 that he did not lie?

With Clementine I always tried to be as honest as possible without going into to much details.

I never would say I did not do something if I did but either give grey area answers, show a little regret if available as a choice or change the subject if possible.

In Episode 1 after Clementine overheard Carley and Lee I spoke to her and told her a grey area answer, something along the line of "I'm not a bad guy" and then changed subject in another answer I think.

In Episode 2 then I chose the most child friendly answer and told her something along the line of "I was on my way to prison before this all started".

She was fine with that as I never outright lied to her.